# How do I find the version number of system libraries in different versions of OS X?

Tags: macos, library, dynamic-library

My specific situation is that I am trying to find out whether Apple bumped the system version of libcairo to 1.12.16 in Yosemite from an earlier version of libcairo in Mavericks.

I can somewhat easily find the version on my current system by inspecting the header files, but I can't seem to find that information online.

**Does there exist a reference online for all the files included in different versions of OS X, or a way to find versions of system libraries (short of having access to a computer running a specific version of OS X)?**

Failing that, I'd appreciate someone running Mavericks taking a peek in `/opt/X11/include/cairo/cairo-version.h` and telling me the version listed there.

Comment: Apple does not make such things public. You may consider visiting an Apple Store as they all their Macs are running Yosemite to gather the information you require.

Comment: Bummer, I thought that might be the case. My issue is that I am running Yosemite and trying to figure out which version of libcairo is in Mavericks.

Comment: /opt/X11 is not part of anything installed by Apple

Comment: Mark's answer below is helpful in showing this - the Open Source pages he linked do not reference libcairo at all.

Comment: Mark's comment above may be more useful--it looks like libcairo may not be included in Yosemite, and something else installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question, in newer releases, `libcairo` is part of cairo, which is part of [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) rather than the Apple-supplied X11 installation. You can find out the supplied version by checking the page for the release in question - for example, [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.7) for 2.7.7.

As has been answered by Mark, the [Apple Open Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) site provides listings of all of the open source software included in each release.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Apple [pages](http://www.opensource.apple.com) listing the open source products in each release. Unfortunately the Yosemite page has not been added yet.